# Return fingerprint and save in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, security, fingerprint

I am trying to write an app using flutter or android studio. The user will login to the app using his fingerprint.

I want to read the fingerprint and save it in a database like firebase. When the user enters his fingerprint, I want to be able to read it my database as a string in order to encrypt later for security purpose

Is it feasible to save the data of the fingerprint in firebase?

Comment: did you manage to read fingerprint as string?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the biometric_storage package along with the local_auth package. biometric_storage will let you store it in firebase.

https://pub.dev/packages/biometric_storage

Comment: local_auth does not return user fingerprint. does it?